# Installing VB6 application and dlls using .net windows installer

Tags: .net, windows, dll, vb6, installation

How can I install a VB 6.0 application and it's related DLL files by creating a .Net(4.0) windows installer ?

Comment: Please revise your question, as there is no concept called .NET windows installer. If you mean Windows Installer (MSI), please state it clearly, and use correct tags.

Answer (score 0):

It's entirely possible to use the .NET Installer to create an install package for a Visual Basic 6 application. However, I would simply recommend using the VB6 Installer that is available as part of the Visual Basic 6 install unless you are using COM Interop and require .NET DLLs as part of your application.